# The meaning of "a sick set of wheels!"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "That's **a sick set of wheels!**"

I've heard it from someone and I'm wondering what the exact meaning is.

I googled the phrase and all I found was a [twitter status](https://twitter.com/thattoygirl/status/929050763405402112).

I know that one of the meanings of ["sick"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sick) as an adjective is:

> very good, excellent

I also found [this](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/set+of+wheels) for "set of wheels":

> a car

So does **"That's a sick set of wheels!"** mean **"That's a very excellent car"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

However, when it comes to its slang use, I prefer the meaning of *sick* as provided by [Your Dictionary](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/slang/more-american-slang.html):

> Sick - This is one of many slang words that mean the opposite of its original meaning. If something is "sick" it actually means it's cool or awesome. Example: Jennifer lives in a sick part of the city. It is full of restaurants and clubs.

In other words:

> That's a cool car!
>   That's an awesome car!

---

Equating it with the more neutral *very good* or *excellent* doesn't convey the nuanced meaning that I'm used to. I would also not expect to hear it used in any formal setting.