# Using pejorative adjectives as a compliment

Tags: word-in-context

Is it correct or usual to use pejorative adjectives when you want to say good things about something, like in the phrase:

> He can do some really nasty tricks with a coin and a scarf

Of course I'm trying to say the tricks he can do are great, everybody enjoys them.

'Nasty' is the only pejorative adjective that comes to my mind and there may be better ones to be used instead - I mean, if that kind of use is really possible.

Comment: Also see *[“The bass drop is so sick!…” - What does it mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/700)* and *[The meaning of “a sick set of wheels!”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182461)* and at EL&U: *[Origin of current slang usage of the word 'sick' to mean 'great'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75017)*, *[Why the opposite meanings of the word “bollocks”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5684)*, *[How and why have some words changed to a complete opposite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22293)*

Comment: Does this never happen in your own native language?  In English there are many, many slang terms  which rebelliously evolved so that older people would not understand what the younger people are saying, because the slang is the exact opposite of the "dictionary" meaning.  For example, back in my day, we would have said *"He can do some really [**bitchin'**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bitchin) tricks ..."*

Comment: @choster  or, from the Boston, [*"My boy's **wicked** smaat"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIdsjNGCGz4)

Comment: Thank you guys for all the insights and links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some dictionaries have definitions for nasty like the following from [Green’s](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/owzmu3y):

> (*orig. US*) first-class, exciting, particularly enjoyable or admirable.

However, this is not a very common definition in my experience and it is not in any of the “major” dictionaries that I checked. In fact “nasty trick” is one of the examples in [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nasty) under “lacking in courtesy or sportsmanship”.

There are several primarily negative words that can mean “awesome” (and are pretty common in this sense, being found in most major dictionaries) such as “wicked”, “sick”, and “killer”.

See also [Inverted meanings](https://web.archive.org/web/20190411111436/https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/05/05/inverted-meanings-sick/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the links.